# How clear Delta Lake Version History on Databricks

Tags: databricks, timedelta, delta-lake

After issuing code `describe history '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1'`

I see I have 28 versions. I would like to clear the version history. I want to carry out a few tests on my table from scratch, but I don't know how to clear the version history. I understand there is the vaccuum command e.g.

```
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaPath)
deltaTable.vacuum(24)
```

But 24 is just the number of hours up until which your versioning is retained.

I would like to completely clear the version history.

Is that possible? Other than deleting the delta folder?

Comment: what do you mean by cleaning? leave only the latest version? or restart from 0?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, I mean starting from 0. Thanks